# How to add custom response and abort request in jersey 1.11 filters

Tags: java, jersey, servlet-filters

I am trying to implement user authentication for rest calls in jersey 1.11 filters.

This is what i have tried

```
package com.ilrn.session.webservices.rest.filter;

import com.ilrn.entity.User;;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilter;

public class CustomFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter{

    @Override
    public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest request) {
        User user = Helper.getCurrentUser();
        if(user == null){
            //Need to add custom response and abort request
        }
        return request;
    }

}
```

Does anyone know any method or something to achieve the same?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In case of error, if you want to send a custom response then you need to throw a WebApplicationException. Create a Response object and send it back using the following exception constructor:

```
WebApplicationException(Response response) 
          Construct a new instance using the supplied response
```

Try this:

```
@Override
public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest request) {
    User user = Helper.getCurrentUser();
    if(user == null){
        ResponseBuilder builder = null;
        String response = "Custom message";
        builder = Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).entity(response);
        throw new WebApplicationException(builder.build());

    }
    return request;
}
```

Comment: @JunedAhsan Thank you for providing the answer. The documentation for Jersey 2.X is better than 1.X and this part was not very clear, until I saw your response.

Comment: @AkshayaAradhya Jersey has improved a lot since inception, both in terms of code and documentation. But I like the framework, because jersey was the first framework I had used for RESTful services, and it made my life simpler.

Comment: @JunedAhsan Please let me know if there is a way to return an ok response in the example shown above.

Comment: @AkshayaAradhya Filters are intended to modify the request. So in general you do not need to abort the request by throwing an exception. Just return the original request. If you still want to abort with an ok response just replace "Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED" with Response.Status.ok.

Comment: @TheoBriscoe Is it possible to return a request without throwing an exception. I want to return an ok response. Throwing an exception seems wrong where there is no need for an exception.

Comment: Not sure why its throwing 500 even if stated 401